# Is it possible to paste the file path into open file dialog in macOS

Tags: macos, mac

I have come from Windows where I could very efficiently copy file paths and paste them into the filename bar in an open file dialog to quickly load, upload or select files.

On macOS, even if I have a file's path, when the open file dialog appears there seems to be no way to enter it directly to load or upload the file in question.

How can I do this? Is it even possible?

I know you can press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> but that just opens a folder, not a file.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As of 2022 `Command + Shift + G` can open files. MacOS 12.4

Comment: Un-F**king**Believable that this is so hidden.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You probably won't like this answer, but the only way I know is to open the terminal and type `open /then/paste/path/to/file.ext` The other way is to just use <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> and paste the whole path. It will bring you to the folder with the file highlighted so you can open it with the program of your choosing. I personally don't know of a better way if you don't like using the terminal.

Comment: Ah, I now see I misunderstood the question :/

Comment: Note: I've been doing cmd+shift+g for years, but on a fresh install of Monterey 12.3 it is not working consistently.

Answer (score 1):

If you can see the file on the desktop [anywhere, not just at ~/Desktop, any open folder], you can drag it straight into the Open filepicker.

If the file can be used, it will already be selected, & ready to hit Enter. If it's an invalid file type, then just the folder will be shown.

[image]

Mac has always been more 'graphically-oriented' than Windows, so this type of structure is often available.

Comment: Worth noting as well: Dragging and dropping a file in to the file picker is something that rightfully feels like a red flag for people who've been in Windows for a long time. In Windows if you drag/drop a file in to the "open file" dialog box, it will *move that file to the folder shown and probably will not warn you*.

Comment: @joshfindit - hmm… didn't know that. Just tested, you're right though it *does* warn you. I suspect that's because the Win file-picker dialog is pretty much the same as any regular explorer window. I'm always amazed at how primitive a lot of it still is, 20 years after they first pushed WinXP out into the bright daylight, blinking like an unearthed mole. Default Folder X is going to scare the bejabus out of you in that case… not only can you do this type of file-picking, but you can do it by clicking right through any open windows or apps in your way, right back to the desktop ;)

Comment: That's exactly it: the Win file-picker dialog *is* a regular explorer window. Personally I'm long past drag-drop feeling like a red flag but after looking at the website I'm now curious about using Default Folder X. Didn't realize the open dialog boxes could be customized and now I want to.

Comment: @joshfindit - I've been using it since before it even had the X - back in the Motorola days.  It's been the only one of my 'truly indispensible' utilities to have survived so long.

Answer (score 0):

MacOS Ventura, "PyCharm -> File Open ->  Command + Shift + G -> paste the path" takes you to the file and allows to select and click Open.